# State chart diagram and multiple actions

Tags: statechart

Can a transition have two or more actions?

For example:

```
       event[condition]/action1;action2
stateA -------------------------------------------> stateB
```

Comment: Can you clarify which notation scheme you're using?

Comment: standar UML state chart diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine#Transition_execution_sequence):

> In UML, a state transition can directly connect any two states. These two states, which may be composite, are designated as the main source and the main target of a transition. Figure 7 shows a simple transition example and explains the state roles in that transition. The UML specification prescribes that taking a state transition involves executing the following actions in the following sequence (**see Section 15.3.14 in OMG Unified Modeling Language (OMG UML), Infrastructure Version 2.2**):
>
> - Evaluate the guard condition associated with the transition and perform the following steps only if the guard evaluates to TRUE.
> - Exit the source state configuration.
> - **Execute the actions associated with the transition.**
> - Enter the target state configuration.

I have been unable to find succint wording to define this in the UML specification, but diagrams and further wording on the Wikipedia article (which is well-referenced) seem to imply that you should use `;` as a separator, as in your example.

However, intuitively I would expect a system's state to change after each action has been taken, so (again intuitively) I would recommend *minimizing* your use of multiple actions per transition. Instead consider adding intermediate states.

Comment: my doubt was the fact that the action is atomic :) thanks anyway